# Web Intelligence : aggregate a count of values

Tags: business-objects, webi

How can I get a variable with the count of A superior or equal to B and A inferior to B to make a pie chart with it ?

I created two var containing each of the count but I don't find how to aggregate them with a function.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a variable to determine the number that fall into each comparison category.

```
Column Comparison=If([a] >= [b]; "A >= B"; "A < B")
```

Then create another variable to count the number of rows that fall into each category.

```
=Count([Column Comparison]; All)
```

You need the optional "All" parameter in the count function so that the duplicate values are counted.

Now you can create a table with your two variables on it. I am not so great with charts so I just copied my table with Column Comparison and Count, click on the edge of it, right-clicked, and chose "Turn Into > Pie Chart".

[image]

Comment: I don't understand, I did exactly the same variables as you but my Count on Comparison give me a total of 1 foreach case. Here are my formula :                    Comparison(Dimension)=If([A]>[B]; "True"; "False")                                                                                   Count(Measure)=Count([Comparison];All)

Comment: Try replacing "True" with "A >= B" and "False" with "A < B". The might be something going on with WebI handling of "True" and "False".

Comment: I changed the picture to show you how is my actual report. I have exactly the same formula and my count is still false ... [A] is a dimension and [B] is a measure is that a problem ?

Comment: What is the datatype of [A]? It would seem that it is not a number since all your comparisons are wrong (3 is not greater then 59). Try converting [A] to a number using the **ToNumber()** function.

Comment: Ok I finally found my mistake. My [A] was a dimension so I tried to make a measure  ToNumber([A]) and it works. My "If" was wrong I inverted my results on the picture.